# Extracting the name of an interaction variable given a full and reduced model

Tags: r

Given a glm model `reduced` containing variable of interest `varofint` and an arbitrary number of additional variables `v1` ... `v[n]` of class `numeric`, `integer`, or `factor` (some of which may be interactions with each other), and a glm model `full` that contains all terms in `reduced` as well as an additional term which is the interaction of `varofint`  and exactly one of the additional variables `v[i]` (this interaction specified using a `:` or `*` in the formula for `full`), how can I extract the name of `v[i]`? I'd prefer solutions that don't rely on regular expressions but rather use the model structure itself.

In the example code, `v[i]` is named `"interaction_var"` and that character vector (`"interaction_var`") is the return value that I want.

```
x <- data.frame(outcome=rbinom(100,1,.3),varofint=rnorm(100), interaction_var=sample(letters[1:3],100,replace=TRUE))

reduced <- glm(outcome~varofint+interaction_var,data=x)
full <- glm(outcome~varofint*interaction_var,data=x)
```

Here's the start of a solution using `sub` which I can't figure out how to finish and makes some assumptions that I don't like:

```
addl_terms <- setdiff(names(coef(full)),names(coef(reduced)))
varname_pluslevel <- sub(".+?:",replacement="", addl_terms[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the term.labels attribute of the terms field in full provides more straightforward access to the interacted variable name:

```
term.labels.reduced = attr(reduced$terms, "term.labels")
term.labels.full = attr(full$terms, "term.labels")
interaction = setdiff(term.labels.full, term.labels.reduced)
strsplit(interaction, ":")[[1]][2]
# [1] "interaction_var"
```

Comment: I think this only works if there aren't any other, unrelated interactions between variables v1...v[n]. Edited the text to make that possibility more clear.

Comment: OK, updated to take the set difference of the term.labels attribute between the two models. From your description, this should just be a single term.

Comment: technically this still relies on a form of regular expressions (strsplit), I'll upvote but leave the question unanswered.